# How to check if time is greater or less than another time in PLSQL

Tags: oracle, syntax, plsql, date-comparison, database-trigger

I am trying to check in my trigger if an inserted record is in the table `TUTPRAC` contains and `CLASSTIME < '9AM' OR > '6PM'`. If this is true then that record is updated with certain fields being changed to `NULL`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER CheckBeforeAfterHours
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF CLASS_TIME ON TUTPRAC
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (:NEW.CLASS_TIME < '09:00' OR > '18:00') THEN
     :NEW.STAFFNO := NULL;
     :NEW.CLASS_DAY := NULL;
     :NEW.CLASS_TYPE := NULL;
     :NEW.ROOMNUM := NULL;
  END IF;
END CheckBeforeAfterHours;
```

**Columns of `TUTPRAC` table:**

```
CLASSID (PK), UNITCODE, STAFFNO, CLASSDAY, CLASSTIME, CLASSTYPE, ROOMNUM
```

The field `CLASSTIME` is set to `varchar(5)`.

I use `Oracle SQLDeveloper`.

**PROBLEM**

my issue is that i keep getting this error when i try to run the trigger:

```
Error(2,36):
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ">" when expecting one of the following:
    ( - + case mod new not null <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
    <a bind variable> continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev
    sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval
    date <a string literal with character set specification>
    <a number> <a single-quoted SQL string> pipe
    <an alternatively-quoted string literal with character set specification>
    <an alternatively
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
IF (:NEW.CLASS_TIME < '09:00' OR :NEW.CLASS_TIME > '18:00') THEN
```

Comment: It depends on the fixed format to make sure the ascii conversion gives correct output.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues here:

> IF (:NEW.CLASS_TIME < '09:00' OR > '18:00')

The syntax is incorrect. You need to mention `:NEW.CLASS_TIME` in the **OR** condition too.

> The field "CLASSTIME" is set to varchar(5)

Then you should go for numeric comparison rather than string comparison. String comparison is based on the **fixed format**, which does a comparison based on the **ASCII** values and not the pure number.

Let's say if you pass `5:00` instead of `05:00`, i.e. when the format is not fixed, then the comparison will give different outputs because the **ASCII** values would be different.

```
SQL> SELECT ascii('05:00'), ascii('5:00') FROM dual;

ASCII('05:00') ASCII('5:00')
-------------- -------------
            48            53
```

**Setup**

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t(A VARCHAR2(5));

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES('04:00');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t VALUES('05:00');

1 row created.

SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.

SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

A
-----
04:00
05:00
```

**String comparison**

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM t WHERE a < '5:00';

A
-----
04:00
05:00

SQL> SELECT * FROM t WHERE a < '05:00';

A
-----
04:00
```

So what happened above? `'05:00'` and `'5:00'` are not same. To avoid this confusion, better go for numeric comparison.

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM t WHERE TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(a, 2, 1)) < 5;

A
-----
04:00
```

**SUBSTR** will extract the numeric part and **TO_NUMBER** will explicitly convert it into number.